# What could be the function of three components of this surge protector?

Tags: surge-protection

An [SPD module](https://www.dehn-international.com/store/d?locale=en&product=900430&type=specification) has the following circuit diagram:

[image]

I'm trying to understand how it functions.

I only know the varistor symbol on the left corner I guess it is a MOV and suppresses transient voltages.

But there are three components there and I'm wondering what each of them functions related to the L, N and E.

For example does the MOV suppress a transient between L and N or L and E? How about the other two components?

Answer (score 0):

The round component on the right, connected between Neutral and Protective Earth, is a gas-discharge tube. It presents a very high impedance until its voltage rating (many times the peak line voltage) is exceeded.

Yes, the item on the lower left is a MOV, as you suspected.

The larger square diagram on the upper left is a puzzle. If you squint just right, you could interpret it as some sort of circuit breaker, intended to open if the MOV fails shorted (which they tend to do).

Comment: it looks like it may be a thermal overload breaker with NC contacts .... do web image search for `thermal breaker symbol`

Comment: It is a thermal cutoff, a permanent disconnect. The Ferraz-Shawmut line of TPMOV's have this built into a 40mm MOV package. Yes, UL and ISO were pushing for a MOV with built-in TCO. That was 10 years ago.

Comment: Is what I understand correct?: MOV is there for the voltage surge protection between L and N. The gas discharge tube is to protect from large spike between L and E or N and E. How about when does the thermal cut off acts or prevents?

Comment: @Sparky256, does that "rising edge" symbol inside the little square mean something like "latching" or "non resettable" ?

Comment: @jsotola. It is spring steel tin plated and soldered to the middle of the MOV disc with low-temp solder. If the MOV gets too hot the solder melts and a spring loaded sheet of mica shoots between the disc and the contact (To stop any arcing). So yes, it is not re-settable by any means. For some designs the mica also hits a tiny button switch with leads up top of the MOV to signal diagnostics of an MOV failure. These designs are often a 3 board stack and cost some bucks to purchase.